# Does Ayurveda see medicinal value in Tamasic and Rajasic foods like onions and garlic?

Tags: food, rajasic, tamasic

Sattvic diets usually eschew onion and especially garlic.  But garlic is considered to have medicinal properties (even today it is given to expectant mothers).

Does scripture make exceptions as to when non-Sattvik food can be taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Charaka Samhita Chapter 27](https://www-easyayurveda-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.easyayurveda.com/2014/08/08/classification-of-foods-and-drinks-charaka-sahmita-sutrasthana-27/?usqp=mq331AQFKAGwASA%3D&amp_js_v=0.1#onion) the usage of onion and garlic as a medicine is prescribed.

> Palandu – **Onion(Allium cepa Linn) aggravates Kapha and alleviates Vata, but it does not alleviate Pitta.** It is useful as a food.
> It is heavy and aphrodisiac. It promotes strength and appetite.[175]

> ***Garlic – Lasuna (Allium Sativum Linn) cues infectious, obstinate skin disease, disease due to the vitiation of Vata and abdominal tumour***. It is unctuous, hot in potency, aphrodisiac pungent and heavy.[176]

[Sushruta Samhita](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/sushruta-samhita-volume-6-uttara-tantra/d/doc143015.html) prescribe onion as a medicine for eye injury.

> As an alternative, the Gutikanjana made up of Trikatu, **Palandu (onion)**, Yashti-madhu, Saindhava, Laksha